# Can't use FluentAssertions/Shouldly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, fluent-assertions, shouldly

I wanted to use FluentAssertions or Shouldly so I added packageReference like this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="4.19.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="nunit" Version="3.10.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.7.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Shouldly" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

but Visual Studio Code still doesn't see FluentAssertions nor Shouldly. I also tried do it by command line using `dotnet add package FluentAssertions --Version 4.19.0` but same result. Do I need other dependencies? Nunit works just fine. I alse did `dotnet restore` after adding references.
I use .net core 2.1.101.

Comment: Make sure the package is compatible with the framework used by your project. Also, check the Dependencies or References section of your project to see if there's more information about the problem.

Comment: And try v5, the newest official version. That one officially supports .NET Core 2.

Comment: Was this issue resolved?